# Python3 Determine if two dictionaries are equal

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, equality

This seems trivial, but I cannot find a built-in or simple way to determine if two dictionaries are equal.

What I want is:

```
a = {'foo': 1, 'bar': 2}
b = {'foo': 1, 'bar': 2}
c = {'bar': 2, 'foo': 1}
d = {'foo': 2, 'bar': 1}
e = {'foo': 1, 'bar': 2, 'baz':3}
f = {'foo': 1}

equal(a, b)   # True 
equal(a, c)   # True  - order does not matter
equal(a, d)   # False - values do not match
equal(a, e)   # False - e has additional elements
equal(a, f)   # False - a has additional elements
```

I could make a short looping script, but I cannot imagine that mine is such a unique use case.

Comment: Why is this marked as duplicate and then the link is to a different question with answers that do not answer this question?

Answer (score 237, accepted):

`==` works

```
a = dict(one=1, two=2, three=3)
b = {'one': 1, 'two': 2, 'three': 3}
c = dict(zip(['one', 'two', 'three'], [1, 2, 3]))
d = dict([('two', 2), ('one', 1), ('three', 3)])
e = dict({'three': 3, 'one': 1, 'two': 2})
a == b == c == d == e
True
```

I hope the above example helps you.

Comment: doesn't work for nested dictionaries

Comment: works just fine for nested dictionaries, i tested with python3.8.

Comment: Does not work for if we compare `ordereddict` with `dict`

Comment: But what about: ```In [1]: x = {"key": True}

In [2]: y = {"key": 1}

In [3]: x==y
Out[3]: True```

Comment: `>>> 1 == True`

`True` @luca.giovagnoli

Answer (score 80):

The good old `==` statement works.

Comment: `==` works. For large dictionaries I would however first make a trivial check, which is compare the number of keys. After all there is no need to go deeper into comparing the values if one dictionary has 2 keys but the other 10.

Comment: That's a good way of thinking but it's not necessary. `==` between two dictionaries is very well optimized and takes into account factors like the one you mentioned.

Comment: For follow up on @Constantine32 's answer, here's the Cython implementation of dict `==` that does exactly what he says. https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/6f535c725b27/Objects/dictobject.c#l1839