# How do I check to see if values in a dict are the exact same?

Tags: python, dictionary

I currently have a dictionary `d` with key: `string`, and values is another `dict`.

**In the `d` dictionary values, how can I check which key and values are ALL the same?**

---

**Example Dictionary:**

zybook, zybooks, zybookz are keys. There can be more than three keys, but I only put two for now. And then the values of `d` are another dict with {file name : number}

```
d = {"zybook": 
        {
         "noodle.json": 5,
         "testing.json": 1,
         "none.json": 5
        },
    "zybooks": 
        {
         "noodle.json": 5,
         "ok.json": 1
        },
    "zybookz":
        {
         "noodle.json": 5
        }
    }
```

---

**Expected Output:**

Because {"noodle.json": 5} {"noodle.json": 5} are both the same in zybook, zybooks, and zybookz the output will create another dictionary with all 3 matches.

```
{"noodle.json": 5}
```

---

**My attempt:**

I honestly don't know how to approach this.

```
d = {"zybook": { "noodle.json": 5, "testing.json": 1, "none.json": 5},
    "zybooks": {"noodle.json": 5, "ok.json": 1},
    "zybookz": {"noodle.json": 5}
}

for key, value in d.items():
    for k, v in value.items():
        if
```

Comment: Does `d` only ever have 2 dicts in it? Or more? If more, do you want the elements that are the same between _all_ the dicts, or different outputs for each pair?

Comment: @DominicD It can have more, I would like the elements that are the same between all dicts.

Comment: @inspiring, What is the expected output for `d = {"zybook": { "noodle.json": 5, "testing.json": 1, "none.json": 5 }, "zybooks": { "noodle.json": 5, "ok.json": 1, "hmm.json": 2, }, "hello": { "wow.json": 7 } }` ?

Comment: @MustafaAydın Because it doesn't match all it should return empty.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python3 Determine if two dictionaries are equal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53348959/python3-determine-if-two-dictionaries-are-equal)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
from functools import reduce
sets = (set(val.items()) for val in d.values())
desired = dict(reduce(set.intersection, sets))
print(desired)
# {'noodle.json': 5}
```

We first form sets out of the `file_name:num` pairs of each dictionary. Then, `reduce` cumulatively looks each set and reduces them to the desired result by taking intersection of those sets. Lastly, converting to a `dict` as needed.

Comment: Thank you, however the solution does not work if there are multiple files with the same name, but different number.

Comment: @inspiring Can you give an example for that case? I couldn't really get what you meant by "multiple files with same name"?

Comment: @inspiring, Actually that doesn't comply with the concept of dictionaries: if there is more than one item with the same key, then only the last one remains. If you print such a dictionary, you will see that `"noodle.json": 5` is missing because is overridden by `"noodle.json": 1"`.

Comment: Oh very true, I completely forgot about that part. Thanks for the help.

Comment: test your output for this `{"zybooks": {"noodle.json": 7, "ok.json": 1}, "zybks": {"noodle.json": 7, "ok.json": 3, "test.json": 7}, "zyks": {"test.json": 7, "ok.json": 1}}`

Comment: @komatiraju032 Gives empty dict as desired?

Comment: @MustafaAydın can you explain on what condition it is empty dict

Comment: @komatiraju032, Because there is no `file:num` pair that exists in _all_ of the dictionaries. See OP's comment under the question.

Comment: @MustafaAydın I didn't see that one he shouldn't mentioned that in the question

Comment: @komatiraju032 I have updated it, that was my mistake.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
from collections import Counter

res = {z[0]: z[1] for z, count in Counter([(k, v) for x in d for k, v in d[x].items()]).items() if count == len(d)}
```

Answer (score 1):

With only the use of embedded Python methods

```py
new = []
for v in d.values():
    new+=list(v.items())
# [('noodle.json', 5), ('testing.json', 1), ('none.json', 5), ('noodle.json', 5), ('ok.json', 1)]

cnt_dict = {v:new.count(v) for v in new}
# {('noodle.json', 5): 3, ('testing.json', 1): 1, ('none.json', 5): 1, ('ok.json', 1): 1}

d2 = {k[0]:k[1] for k,v in cnt_dict.items() if v > 1}
print(d2)
# {'noodle.json': 5}
```